# Recuperar una variable enviada a servidor

Tags: javascript, java, servidor

Desde una función JavaScript he enviado un String con el siguuiente método:

```
zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.Widget.$('$nuevaPeticion'), 'onNueva', resultado, {toServer:true}));
```

Siendo resultado el String que envío. Mi intención ahora es recoger en una clase java ese String para poder manipularlo, pero no encuentro forma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponiendo que en el servidor tienes todo preparado para recibir el dato, tendrías que utilizar una función así.

```
@Listen("onTest=#nuevaPeticion")
    public void onTest(Event evt){    
      String a = evt.getData().toString();
      Messagebox.show(a);
    }
```

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Mirate esta página:
https://www.video2brain.com/es/tutorial/obtener-datos-de-servidor-y-actualizarlos-a-tiempo-real
Creo que es justamente eso lo que estas buscando.